# Why doesn't action fire in my react\redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently, I'm working on a small application that utilizes modals. I don't want to use 'ready-to-use' packages like react-modal and instead decided to try to do it on my own.

1) A **reducer** in `src/reducers/modalReducer.js`

```
const modalReducer = (state = {
  show: true,
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_MODAL':
      console.log('reducer worked out')
      state = {...state, show: !state.show }
      break
    default:
        return state
  }
}

export default modalReducer
```

My `reducers/index.js`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import modalReducer from './modalReducer'

const reducers = combineReducers({
  modal: modalReducer
})

export default reducers
```

2) A **store** in `src/store.js`

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers/index'

export default createStore(reducer)
```

3) A **Modal** component in `src/components/Modal.js`. I want this component to be reusable and contain input forms which I'll add later.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleModal } from '../actions/index'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import '../css/Modal.css'

class Modal extends Component {

  render () {
    if(!this.props.show) {
      return (<h1>FUC YOU</h1>)
    }
    console.log('HELLLO' + this.props.show)

    return (
      <div className='backdrop'>
        <div className='my-modal'>
          <div className='footer'>
            <button className='close-btn' onClick={ () => toggleModal }>
              X
            </button>
          </div>
          <h1>{ this.props.title }</h1>
          <hr/>
          <div>
            { this.props.contents }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { show: state.modal.show }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    toggleModal: () => dispatch(toggleModal())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Modal)
```

My problem is that when I'm pressing the button **x**, in my modal nothing happens. It means that I did something wrong when was dispatching actions, but I have no idea what I missed...

At this point I just want my empty modal to be closed when the x button is pressed.

In my index.js I have the following structure:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store.js'

import App from './components/App'
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store} >
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()
```

My **Modal** component is within **App**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually *calling* the `toggleModal()` action creator.  In addition, you're referencing the imported function, not the function you're getting as props:

```
onClick={ () => toggleModal }
```

The immediate fix would be:  `onClick={ () => this.props.toggleModal() }`.

Having said that, there's two other ways you can improve this code.

First, you can pass `toggleModal` directly as the handler for `onClick`, like:

```
onClick={this.props.toggleModal}
```

Second, you can replace the `mapDispatch` function by using the "object shorthand" syntax supported by `connect`:

```
import {toggleModal} from "../actions";

const actions = {toggleModal};

export default connect(mapState, actions)(Modal);
```

Beyond that, I'd encourage you to read my post [Practical Redux, Part 10: Managing Modals and Context Menus](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/), which specifically shows how to implement modal dialogs using React and Redux, and points to additional resources on the topic.